# How to Send Telerik Report in Mail Attachment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, smtp, telerik-reporting

I'm curious about, is there any possibility to send Telerik Report like mail attachment?

Is there any information about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following link will show you a simple way of how to attach a Telerik report as an email attachment. http://www.telerik.com/blogs/send-telerik-report-as-email-attachment  
Simply render the report in a format you wish into a memory stream and then attach that memory stream as an attachment to your email.

Comment: Hi @Bradley. I know that article and i read that and also try but my problem is I'm using Mvc project and How can i send Telerik report like a parameter. Unfortunately in that article they dont talk about this. If i miss something please tell me! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by like a parameter? I do not fully understand what you mean by that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using MVC application and i 'm sending values with ajax requests so when i click send mail button that button calls ajax request and send parameters to controllor in this case  '
void MailReport(Telerik.Reporting.Report report, string from, string to, string subject, string body)   
   {  ' Telerik.Reporting.Report report is my parameter and it comes to my controller 'null' this is problem